# How to change the spacing between words and characters?

Tags: java, itext

I want to set the text alignment to justified, but I don't want iText to add any extra space between the characters (see figure 1). I prefer space between words as shown in figure 2.

[image]

With this code, I get the result shown in figure 1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {

    Document document = new Document();
    String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop";
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(path+"\\abc.pdf"));
    BaseFont bf1 = BaseFont.createFont(
        BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, "iso-8859-9", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font font1 = new Font(bf1);
    document.open();

    Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph();

    paragraph2.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
    paragraph2.setFont(font1);
    paragraph2.setIndentationLeft(20);
    paragraph2.setIndentationRight(20);
    paragraph2.add("HelloWorld HelloWorld HelloWorld HelloWorld HelloWorld"+ 
        "HelloWorld HelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorld"+
        "HelloWorld HelloWorld HelloWorld HelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorld");
    document.add(paragraph2);

    document.close();
}
```

How can I change this code to get a result like in figure 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the [SpaceCharRatioExample](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/SpaceCharRatioExample) to find out how to create a PDF that looks like [space_char_ratio.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/space_char_ratio.pdf):

[image]

When you justify a paragraph, iText will add extra space between the words and between the characters. By default, iText will add 2.5 times more space between words than between characters.

You can change this default like using the `setSpaceCharRatio()` method:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    writer.setSpaceCharRatio(PdfWriter.NO_SPACE_CHAR_RATIO);
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
    paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
    paragraph.setIndentationLeft(20);
    paragraph.setIndentationRight(20);
    paragraph.add("HelloWorld HelloWorld HelloWorld HelloWorld HelloWorld"+ 
        "HelloWorld HelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorld"+
        "HelloWorld HelloWorld HelloWorld HelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorld");
    document.add(paragraph);
    // step 5
    document.close();
}
```

In this case, we tell iText not to add any space between the characters, only between the words: `PdfWriter.NO_SPACE_CHAR_RATIO`. Well, as a matter of fact we tell iText to add 10,000,000 times more space between the words than between the characters, which is almost the same thing.

Comment: It's a shame no-one seems to have consulted a typographer when designing iText. A typographer would want to control them both separately.

Comment: @EJP So then you would have two values, but the two values wouldn't be independent of each other. You'd always be able to derive one value from the other, hence one value is sufficient, isn't it?